# Is 得弄 one word or two in 首先得弄清楚我们需要什么?

Tags: grammar, meaning, expressions

I have 首先**得弄**清楚我们需要什么。

I see 得弄清楚 is a fairly common combination of words. Is 得弄 one word or 2 words here? Should I read de nong or dei nong?

Should I translate the sentence to

1. 'First we **need to** find out what we need.', or rather
2. 'First we **should be** clear about what we need.', or
3. 'First we **should make** clear about what we need.'

Which of 1,2 or 3 do you prefer, or would you rather suggest something else?

I found this sentence: 希尔得弄个清楚。= Hill had to find out for certain.

Answer (score 10):

- 得 : got to / must / have to **ABC** *must* / *need* / *should be*
- 弄清楚 : **ABC** *make clear; figure out*

得 is read děi when it means must/have to/need to.

I would translate `首先得弄清楚我们需要什么。` as:

*We first need to figure out what we need.*

Answer (score 4):

2 words.
in this case, 得=have to, 弄=make
example:
1.我们首先得吃饭.(we have to eat first)
2.我要把这个问题弄清楚.(I gonna make this problem clear)

and the pronunciation is "dei nong"
translation 1 is what I prefer, but 2 and 3 are also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

得弄, are neither one word nor two words because they are not to be read together.

The sentence structure is:-

首先, (first and foremost),得弄清楚, (decide / work out clearly), 我们需要什么, (what is it we really need)

The sentence works just as well without the 得 as, in my view, it is superfluous.